# Power BI Countdown timer with conditional formatting

Tags: timer, powerbi, visualization

I am trying to create:

- a 5 minute count down timer
- Turns the number orange at 1 minute
- Red at 10 seconds
- Refreshes with 1 specific filter within the page

Any pointers? TIA!

I've been trying to use Deneb to create this feature but my current experience is pretty limited and I am pretty stumped.